# ERROR [HY000] [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-01406: fetched column value was truncated

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, odbc

```
using (OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection())
{
    conn.ConnectionString = "MY CONNECTIONSTRING";
    conn.Open();


    //This line throws an error when running against an Oracle XE driver.
    using(DataTable mytable = conn.GetSchema(OdbcMetaDataCollectionNames.Columns))
    {
       //code that will analyze returned schema.
    }
}
```

The error I am seeing is:

ERROR [HY000] [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-01406: fetched column value was truncated

Anyone have any ideas as to why I would get this error when I'm simply requesting the database schema? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using an `OdbcConnection` instead of an Oracle-specific data provider?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an earlier version of Oracle than 10.2.0.3 then this could be a bug.
see this https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=375889
and this [ora-01406 Error when fetching values using OCI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458881/ora-01406-error-when-fetching-values-using-oci)

Answer (score 0):

You may increase the "Fetch Buffer Size" in your ODBC driver configuration. In my case it was set to 64000 and I increased it to 999999 which solved the problem for me (using the very old Oracle ODBC 11.02.00.01 driver version).